Powershell script to clear Windows "Recent Files" doesn't clear files, but clears quick access shortcuts somehow
I found and modified this code to get the recent files and remove any that were made on the day the script is run:
#remove from past day
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$path = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

Though I can check the folder manually and see that it has the files I want. I verified that the USERPROFILE value is correct as well by setting it to a variable and echoing it.
Despite everything seeming to be correct, it somehow removes my Quick Access shortcuts and NOT the files.


I'm pretty sure you want -gt not -lt if your goal is to remove any items that were created within the last 24 hours.

Oh crap... duh. Thanks!

Try this code, this should solve your problem:
$PathToFolder = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
$LimitTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

# Delete the files based on the limit time
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToFolder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -gt $LimitTime } | Remove-Item -Force

